# Reflection: invoke method inside static field

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

```
Type type_class_a = ....;
Type type_class_b = type_class_a.GetField("name_b").FieldType;
MethodInfo method = type_class_b.GetMethod("method");
method.Invoke(type_class_b,new object[] {"test_string"});
```

in dll

```
public class class_a
{
    public static class_b name_b = new class_b();
}
public class class_b
{
    public void method(string data)
    {
    }
}
```

but i got error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    Additional information: Object does not match target type.

Then how to invoke it?
Thankyou.

Comment: The first argument of `method.Invoke` should be an *instance* of `class_b`, not the type. You are invoking an instance method - you still need an instance.

Comment: Thankyou, it work. `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type_class_b); type_class_a.GetField("name_b").SetValue(type_class_a,instance )`

Comment: When you create an instance using Activator.CreateInstance(...) another object is created in memory. So, in case if the static member `name_b` of your `class_a` is stored at memory location 0x1234, then the object created using Activator.CreateInstance will not be that object but a new object which might be stored at memory address 0x9876. Hence, you might not have the same value of fields and properties in this object created using Activator.CreateInstance; and also this will lead to many time consuming debugging hours (because you will not be able to identify where values are lost)

Comment: I don't think so. **Create instance > do any with instance > Set instance to field** and **Create instance > Set instance to field > do any with instance**. It the same result (tested) -> same memory address (pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your class `class_a` defines the object of type `class_b` and `class_b` contains a method named `method`, your approach will be as follows (in dll)

1. Get `Type` of `class_a` object in your code (store in `class_a_type` variable of type `Type`)
2. Get `FieldInfo` object of the `class_a_type` object for `name_b` object (store it in `a_field_info` variable of type `FieldInfo`)
3. Get object of that field type (in your case, the object instance `name_b`) in an object by calling GetValue function of the `FieldInfo` object (store it in `b_object` variable of type `object`)
4. Get `MethodInfo` object for the method (named `method`) in the above `b_object` object by calling `b_object.GetType().GetMethod("method")` (and store it in `b_method` object of type `MethodInfo`)
5. Invoke the method by calling `Invoke` function on the above `b_method` object and passing the `b_object` as first parameter (the object on which to call the function) and `null` as second parameter (the array of parameters to be passed to the function.

**A bit confusion???** Find the example below:

```
Type class_a_type = class_a_object.GetType();
FieldInfo a_field_info = class_a_type.GetField("name_b");

object b_object = a_field_info.GetValue(class_a_object);
MethodInfo b_method = b_object.GetType().GetMethod("method");

b_method.Invoke(b_object, null);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the FieldInfo of name_b, you need to call FieldInfo.GetValue(null) to get the actual value (the instance of class_b). You also need the MethodInfo of typeof(class_b).method.

Once you have both of those, you can call methodInfo.Invoke passing in the instance of class_b.